# Passwordless `smtpmail-send-it` and queue

Tags: smtpmail

my current mu4e setup uses `MSMTP` utility to send out emails. Unfortunately if I want to use queues I have to use `smtpmail.el` which requires me either to (1) save my password in cleartext in `.authinfo`, (2) enter my password every time, (3) enter my PGP passphrase when using `.authinfo.gpg`. None of these solutions is very convenient.

Is there a way to convince `smtpmail.el` to retrieve my password from an Emacs lisp function, possibly without storing it for too long? I have an Emacs lisp function that extract the password from the keychain, so that would be ideal.

Comment: You don't have to use auth-source's authinfo backend. There's a 'Secret Service Api' one that integrates with the Gnome Keyring and the KDE Wallet. See <https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/auth/Secret-Service-API.html>

Comment: Thank you. It seems that this solution is only for GNU/Linux, but I need a solution that works on macOS too. I see that there are auth-sources types for macOS key chain. That could be an option.

Comment: Make use of gpg-agent. You can use it to avoid entering the passphrase each time from your elisp function  or  instruct msmtp to extract the password from a command.